# get submenu id, without parent id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Good afternoon, I have a menu of categories and subcategories. It is formed from the values ​​in the database. I want to get the id of the selected menu item or submenu. But when I click on a submenu, it first displays the id of the submenu and then the id of all the categories that this submenu belongs to.
I'm tracking click on class "category-li" and usually use jquery. But if you know another way, then I will be glad. Thank you.

```
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul class="category">
            <li class="subcategory category-li" id="category-name">category
                <ul class="category">
                    <li class="category-li" id="1">books
                        <ul class="category">
                            <li class="category-li" id="4">art
                                <ul class="category">
                                    <li class="category-li" id="6">modern</li>
                                    <li class="category-li" id="7">classic</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="category-li" id="5">scientific</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="category-li" id="2">home</li>
                    <li class="category-li" id="3">kids</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".category-li li").click(function () {
            let id = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(id);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to post the rendered HTML instead of the templating markup, so it will be easier for one to reproduce the issue. [How to create a snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.stopPropagation();` do the trick:

```
        $(".category-li li").click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            let id = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(id);
        });
```